# shm_open() function no such file or directory

Tags: c, posix

I'm trying to create a new shared memory file using shm_open(), but I'm getting errno 2 (No such file or directory).

```
shm_open ("/DIAG_public", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR | S_IWGRP | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
```

I've tried creating my own standalone app to run shm_open with the same name and options, and this *is* successful...

So checked that /dev/shm has `drwxrwxrwt` permissions and that the process running the actual code has `-rwxrwxrwx` permissions.

Also, `mount | grep shm` returns:

```
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
```

I'm out of ideas... any suggestions on what could be going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I assume you meant the _program_ has `rwxrwxrwx` permissions - processes do not have permissions. By the way 0777 is a very _bad_ set of permissions for an program to have.

Comment: Hi, yes sorry, program not process. I have no control over the permissions given to that program :P but I believe it's given 0777 because it's actually something written for an external piece of hardware (which I'm now trying to get to run on linux to speed up testing).

Comment: Did someone find a solution? I have the same problem!

Comment: Try running your program under `strace` to see which syscall is failing and with which arguments.

Comment: maybe you should show your code snip

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are actually passing O_CREAT. Only that seems to be giving this error.

Man page says ENOENT is returned only under two conditions. For shm_open only first one seems to be valid though.

```
man shm_open
ERRORS
       On failure, errno is set to indicate the cause of the error.  Values which may appear in errno include the following:

    ...

        ENOENT An attempt was made to shm_open() a name that did not exist, and O_CREAT was not specified.

        ENOENT An attempt was to made to shm_unlink() a name that does not exist.
```