# Shared memory: shm_open fails

Tags: c, shared-memory

I'm trying to create a shared memory space on Linux in C, but `shm_open` keeps failing and returning -1. Could this be because I'm not the root user on this computer?

Here's what I'm trying:

```
char *name = "name";
int shm_fd = shm_open(name, O_CREAT|O_RDWR, 0666);
```

but it always returns -1. Any suggestions? I've heard that names for `shm_open` need to start with a /, so I've tried `char *name = "/name"` too but still the same. Please help!

Comment: What is `errno`? Use `perror` or `error`  to report errors and get the error messages automatically.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart `perror` was giving a "No such file or directory". But strangely, I restarted the computer, and it works without errors now. I would still like to understand what could have been happening though, if you have any ideas!

Comment: You might check whether a node "name" is under /dev/shm/

Comment: There's a similar question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985940/shm-open-function-no-such-file-or-directory), with an answer suggesting to check that both flags O_CREAT and O_RDWR were correctly set. That solved it for me (I was missing the first one)